# program keeps crashing when one of the textbox is not filled in

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

im currently trying to insert the code to appear a popup when a textbox is empty saying "Please fill in your credentials" but nothing seems to be working out. here is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class AddNewStudent
    Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection
    Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommand
    Dim con = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ASSIGNMENT\vbnassignmentfinal.accdb;"
    Dim cmdDelete As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmdUpdate As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cmdSearch As New OleDbCommand
    Private Sub AddNewStudentSD_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cnnOLEDB.ConnectionString = con
        cnnOLEDB.Open()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click

        txtsem.ResetText()
        txtsfn.ResetText()
        txtsid.ResetText()
        txtsln.ResetText()
        txtsph.ResetText()
        txtint.ResetText()
        cmbgen.ResetText()


    End Sub

    Private Sub btnHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnhome.Click
        UserHomepage.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsubmit.Click
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "Insert into student Values(" + txtsid.Text + ",'" + txtint.Text + "','" + txtsfn.Text + "','" + txtsln.Text + "', '" + cmbgen.Text + "', " + txtsph.Text + ", '" + txtsem.Text + "');"
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB


        If txtsid.Text = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox("Please fill in your credentials ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Verify")
            Me.Show()

        End If

        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to proceed?", "Proceed", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If DialogResult.Yes Then
            AccomodationStatus.Show()
            Me.Hide()


        ElseIf DialogResult.No Then
            Me.Show()
            AccomodationStatus.Hide()
        End If


    End Sub

End Class
```

where am i doing wrong?

this is my current problem after the solution:

[image: error box shows up]

[image: this is the error showing after pressing ok]

Comment: 0 is not empty. Change to `if txtsid.Text = ""` (or. if you prefer,  `if txtsid.Text = vbNullString`). And I assume you should execute your SQL *after* checking, not before

Comment: now it shows the message box, but it crashes after that.how to avoid from it crashing and returning back to the form?

Comment: What do you mean with *"crashing"* and where does it happen?

Comment: Post your error! Without it we have no idea what is happening.

Comment: @FunThomas i have added a picture please view it thanks

Comment: @MihaiAdrian i have posted two pictures please view it thanks

Comment: Provide full code! What SqlCommand is cmdInsert? The error suggests the problem is with your SqlCommand.

Comment: @MihaiAdrian i updated already sorry for the inconvienience

Comment: Why do you flag your question as VBA when it is VB.Net? As the error comes when you execute the sql statement: Have you checked the content of `CommandText` with the debugger? Can you issue this statement manually against the database?

Comment: FWIW you should use `MessageBox.Show` and `String.Empty`, not the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` legacy stuff like `MsgBox` and `vbNullString`

Answer (score 0):

You have not concatenated your CommandText properly.

Try this :

```
cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [student] Values('" & txtsid.Text & "','" & txtint.Text & "','" & txtsfn.Text & "','" & txtsln.Text & "','" & cmbgen.Text & "','" & txtsph.Text & "','" & txtsem.Text & "')"
```

As you are not providing column names, also check of the table has as many columns as you are inserting values for.

Comment: One of the many reasons to use command parameter rather than to tinker a large string with all values.

Comment: @FunThomas  I agree! :)